# Output file iterativ resolution

Tags: output, cplex, opl

How can I create an object   f  var ofile = new IloOplOutputFile("Resultat.txt"); ; and call the object on my post process each time the model will be solved , my purpose is to create an object  " ofile "  one time  and call it, at each time my model will be solved and display the results in a file, I don't wanna do this on the main bloc  because I have a lot of parameters.

my model is an iterative one so it solves for different data and I am trying to output at  each time the results .

At this time it returns me only the last the iteration because at each time I am calling the postprocess it's creats a new file and crush the last results ...

Another solution would be to copy the result that display Cplex/Opl  on its script box directly on my file , but i dont know how to do it with the language of Cplex/OPL ..

Regards thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not hesitate to use the append parameter:

```
IloOplOutputFile(path, append)


Parameters:
    path - Optional: The path of the file to open. 
    append - Optional: If true, sets the stream position at the end of the file.
```

PS: same question at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=575928e1-eb6e-4468-9a10-46c6fe8fb73a&ps=25